# Retrieving data using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

how to retrieve data from jsp using jquery?
I created a basic form and i stored the values into mysql database.Then I retrieved the database values using jsp.Now I want my jquery to obtain those values from jsp code and print those values.
this is my code for jsp

```
<%
    String vlemail=request.getParameter("vlemail");
    try
    {
    String str="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/licet";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con=null;
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(str,"root","");
    Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("select Password from record where Email='"+vlemail+"'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
    String a=rs.getString("Password");
    }
     out.println("Retrieved" );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    out.println(e);
    out.println("Not retrieved");
    }
    %>
```

And this is my html code

```
<body style="background-color:#663366">
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Authentica</h1>
      <p>Have an account already? Then login</p>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="newjsp.jsp" method="GET">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email" style="color:#FFFFFF">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="vlemail" id="lemail" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now I want my jquery to get the data from jsp and print it

Answer (score 0):

> **home.jsp**

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vlemail" id="lemail" placeholder="Enter email" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit" id="aaa" value="Submit" name="Submit">
  <br />
  <div id="javaquery"><b>Name will be displayed here</b></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aaa").click(function() {
    var value = $("#lemail").val();

    $.get("data.jsp", {
      q: value
    }, function(data) {
      $("#javaquery").html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

> **data.jsp**

```
<body>

  <%
            String name = "";
            String q = request.getParameter("q");
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.146:3306/tables", "root", "Abcdefg1");
                Statement smt = con.createStatement(); //Create Statement to interact
                ResultSet r = smt.executeQuery("select * from employee where(email='" + q + "');");
                while (r.next()) {
                    name = r.getString("name");
                }
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>
    Name:
    <%out.print(name);%>
</body>
```